# Dart 'classwork.dart' File Reading Error: No Such File or Directory - Solutions for a Newbie

Tags: android, dart

`[Error when reading : No such file or directory.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbIjk.png)

My Dart version :3.0.3

I'm new I don't understand anything about Dart and Android Studio .I don't know how to fix it please help . I really need you help to continue study Dart

`

Comment: About which file or directory are you talking? What is it that you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You have put your Dart files in the [`.dart_tool`](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/private-files#dart_tool) directory, which is not appropriate. Move them into `lib/`, and make sure you are in the right working directory in your console.